# Problema con "" al mandar variable por método GET

Tags: php, html, get

estoy enviando por metodo GET una variable

```
while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
    $html .= '<tr>';
    //$html .= '<td>' . $row['Incrementable'] . '</td>';
    $html .= '<td>' . $row['CvePersonal'] . '</td>';
    $html .= '<td>' . $row['CtaBanco'] . '</td>';
    $html .= '<td>' . $row['CveContrato'] . '</td>';
    $html .= '<td>' . $row['TipoEmpleado'] . '</td>';
    $html .= '<td>' . $row['Inicio'] . '</td>';
    $html .= '<td>' . $row['Fin'] . '</td>';
    $html .= '<td>' . $row['UltDia'] . '</td>';
    $html .= '<td>' . $row['CodCategoria'] . '</td>';
    $html .= '<td>' . $row['PrimaVac'] . '</td>';
    $html .= '<td>' . $row['HrsMen'] . '</td>';
    $html .= '<td>' . $row['CostoHra'] . '</td>';

    $clave = $row['Incrementable'];

    $html .= '<td>
    <a href="depurar.php?Incrementable=$clave"><img src="img/expedientes/editar.png" height="40" width="40" /></a>
    </td>';

    $html .= '<td><img src="img/expedientes/eliminar.png" height="40" width="40" title="Eliminar"></td>';
    $html .= '</td>';
}
```

Necesito enviar la variable clave, sé que para mandar por método GET es con la sintaxis que escribí, el problema es que si uso `''` para la variable `$clave` me manda un error de sintaxis, así como está escrito únicamente llega una cadena de texto `$clave`

Espero haber sido claro con mi pregunta, antes que nada, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás usando comillas simples para asignar esto:

```
$html .= '<td>
    <a href="depurar.php?Incrementable=$clave"><img src="img/expedientes/editar.png" height="40" width="40" /></a>
    </td>';
```

y dentro, si te fijas, intentas usar la variable $clave, la cual **nunca** se resuelve así con comillas simples, pues no se interpreta como tal.

Prueba con la [notación de concatenación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.string.php) de este modo:

```
$html .= '<td>
    <a href="depurar.php?Incrementable='.$clave.'"><img src="img/expedientes/editar.png" height="40" width="40" /></a>
    </td>';
```

a ver si así lo arreglas.

Piensa que no es lo mismo usar comillas simples que dobles, pues las dobles si que interpretan variables de PHP, pero en este caso, si las usaras, tendría que ser así:

```
$html .= "<td>
    <a href=\"depurar.php?Incrementable=$clave\"><img src=\"img/expedientes/editar.png\" height=\"40\" width=\"40\" /></a>
    </td>";
```

lo cual no recomiendo pues debes escapar todas las comillas dobles que contengan, aunque si te fijas la $clave ya no va concatenada y se resolvería bien.

[Aquí encontrarás más información sobre las diferencias entre comillas simples y dobles](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php).

Comment: Muchísimas gracias no encontraba la forma de acceder a la variable, eres un genio Graciassss